# Program is searching for chrome driver in wrong path instead of Executable path mentioned in script

Tags: java, eclipse, path, selenium-chromedriver, executable

I know that many question has been raised related to executable path issue in `Selenium WebDriver`, However, The issue I am explaining below one is different.

I am giving chrome driver path correctly in the script.
path:‪`F:\\chromedriver.exe`
But system is searching in different path during execution:The driver executable does not exist: `E:\WorkSpace\Flipkart\‪F:\chromedriver.exe`

I don't know why it is looking into different path which is completely wrong. Please provide your suggestion and views related to this issue.

```
public class Engine {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "‪F:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bypassed this issue using File class. Please find the following code.

```
public class Engine {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    File filename = new File("F:\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filename.getAbsolutePath());

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
     }
```